# How to use Chartboost Analytics with swift?

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode, analytics, chartboost

I've imported Chartboost via headers and cannot get CBAnalytics from Chartboost.framework to call next function in Swift.

```
+ (void) trackInAppPurchaseEvent:(NSData *)transactionReceipt 
                         product:(SKProduct *)product;
```

I followed these instructions
https://answers.chartboost.com/hc/en-us/articles/205606995
https://answers.chartboost.com/hc/en-us/articles/204639335-Post-Install-Analytics-Event-Level-Tracking-via-SDK#ios

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a pre-existing Obj-C project, so I jury-rigged it to show this call in Swift.

Here's the SDK header import I needed to add to my project's `Bridging-Header.h` file:

```
#import <Chartboost/CBAnalytics.h>
```

Here's my actual Swift call:

```
//Swift
@objc func makeChartboostPIACall(myReceipt:NSData, myProduct:SKProduct) {
    CBAnalytics.trackInAppPurchaseEvent(myReceipt, product: myProduct)
}
```

It SHOULD be that easy, but here's a little more detail on where those values I was passing in are coming from:

In my case, I was passing in the values from my Obj-C code:

```
//Obj-C
[mySwiftInstance makeChartboostPIACall:transaction.transactionReceipt myProduct:myProduct];
```

I made that call after I had just confirmed that a payment transaction had successfully completed (`SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased`). Thus, "transaction" is a `SKPaymentTransaction` object, and "myProduct" is the matching `SKProduct` of what had just been purchased.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StoreKit/Reference/SKPaymentTransaction_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKPaymentTransaction/transactionReceipt
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StoreKit/Reference/SKProduct_Reference/index.html

It's worth noting that `transaction.transactionReceipt` is deprecated as of iOS 7, and this is the recommended method to use going forward:

```
//Obj-C
NSURL *receiptURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] appStoreReceiptURL];
NSData *receipt = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:receiptURL];
```

Comment: It's also worth noting that if this isn't working as expected, there may be something specific about the integration you're using that's unexpected. If so, could you email into support@chartboost.com with further details? We'd be happy to look into this in-depth and then come back here to update the answer.